# Dynamically Checking Checkboxes from Array

Tags: javascript, php, html, date

Given Data in a varchar mysql field 1,3,6

I have 7 checkboxes for SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT
I have stored the days that need to be checked but I want to display all non checked and checked boxes

So for my example output will be SUN(checked) MON TUE(checked) WED THU FRI(checked) SAT 
These 7 words represent checkboxes. assumed the data is a varchar mysql field 1,3,6

My code works partially because it will only show the first day that needs to be checked but not the other ones. It does However display the non-checked checkboxes which is good.

Here is my code:
BTW sorry if the formatting is weird! I am new here.

```
 <? php
  $RecurringDays = explode(",", $recur['weekday']);
 for ($i = 1; $i <= count($RecurringDays) - 1; $i++) {
     if ($RecurringDays[$i - 1] == "1") {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='0' checked='checked' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Sun </label></td>";
         continue;
     } else {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='0' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Sun </label></td>";
     }
     if ($RecurringDays[$i - 1] == "2") {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='1' id='1' checked='checked' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Mon </label></td>";
         continue;
     } else {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='1' id='1'  />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Mon </label></td>";
     }
     if ($RecurringDays[$i - 1] == "3") {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='2' id='2' checked='checked' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Tue </label></td>";
         continue;
     } else {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='2' id='2' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Tue </label></td>";
     }
     if ($RecurringDays[$i - 1] == "4") {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='3' id='3' checked='checked' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Wed </label></td>";
         continue;
     } else {
         echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='3' id='3' />";
         echo "<label for='0'>Wed </label></td>";
     }
```

Comment: If the difference with the checked and unchecked boxes is just the "checked" attribute, it would be better to remove all the "ifs" and just do something like: <input type='checkbox' name='1' id='1' <? if (..) { echo 'checked="checked"'; }  ?> >.

Comment: and... Why not use an array and loop through it instead of hard coding each values? $ar = array('0' => 'Sun', '1' => 'Mon' ...) and then foreach ($ar as $id => $day) ...

Comment: Ok so I have an array and I loop trough it I have done <input type='checkbox' name='1' id='1' <? if (..) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> > but I would have to go trough the array each time it there not a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will echo only the days in the varchar, as per your code (as they are in the for loop). I recommend the following edit.

```
<?php
//The days in the database
//$recurringDays = explode(",", $recur['weekday']); //expected an array(1,3,6) 
$recurringDays = array(1,3,6) ;
//The days in a the week    
$days = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++ ){
    if(in_array($i,$recurringDays)){
     echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='".$i."' checked='checked' />";
         } else {
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='".$i."' />";             
         }
     echo "<label for='".$i."'>".$days[$i]." </label></td>";
    }
```

Comment: I had to fix some errors but here is the working code //The days in the database
$recurringDays = explode(",", $recur['weekday']); //expected an array(1,3,6) 

//The days in a the week    
$dayss = array("Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat");

     for ($i = 0; $i <= 6; $i++) {
     if(in_array($i,$recurringDays)){
       echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='".$i."' checked='checked' />";
        } else {
             echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='0' id='".$i."' />";             
        }
   echo "<label for='".$i."'>".$dayss[$i]." </label></td>";
   }